# Antd Form through multiple components

Tags: reactjs, antd

i'm trying to create a React Antd form but my form is splitted into multiple pages (components) and i can't collect my form items' values because they're located in the nested (inner) components.

i've create a main Form component which has the form container, , and the submit button for the form

but my Form items <FormItem ..> are nested in inner components which represents the form pages.
to be clear this is the structure

```
function SignupForm(){
... 
<Form>

 <PageComponent /> //FormItems are inside this nested component

 <Button> submit </Button>
</Form>

}
```

but unfortunately this isn't working, when i hit the submit button, the form values aren't colleced from inner components which has the

how can i fix that? please help

Comment: What's the antd version？

Comment: Latest version 5.14.2